# Counting records that changed between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables `tickets` and `threads` and `threadstatuses` with the simplified schema here-

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticketStatuses_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=83670708 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `threads` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tickets_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `assign_ticketStatuses_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31046 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ticketstatuses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can see that both `threads` and `tickets` have reference to the ticketstatus.  That allows me to show when a ticket changed status.  What I need to query is to get an aggregate of the number of tickets that had each status for each day in the given date range.  So the user could ask "tell me how many tickets were open or closed (or whatever else) for each day the past 7 days."  The end goal here is to build a time-series chart.

Anyways, I have banged together an admittedly over complex and not very performant query that gives me the results for a single day, but I cannot figure out how to fix it to give the counts for each day.  I don't need to know how many tickets changed to the status on that day (which would be easy), but HAD that status on a given day.  Here is what I came up with-

```
    SELECT SUM(total) as total, name
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(th.id) as total, ts.name
        FROM ticketstatuses ts
        INNER JOIN threads th ON ts.id = th.assign_ticketStatuses_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN threads nextThread ON th.tickets_id = nextThread.tickets_id
            AND nextThread.createdAt > th.createdAt
            AND nextThread.assign_ticketStatuses_id IS NOT NULL
        WHERE /* Need something different here for the range */ DATE('2015-03-04') BETWEEN DATE(th.createdAt) AND DATE(nextThread.createdAt)
        GROUP BY th.assign_ticketStatuses_id

        UNION

        /* Gives me tickets that are new (have not had a status change) */
        SELECT SUM(c) as total, name
        FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(t.id) c, ts.name as name
            FROM ticketstatuses ts
            INNER JOIN tickets t ON ts.id = t.ticketStatuses_id
            INNER JOIN threads th ON th.tickets_id = t.id
            WHERE th.assign_ticketStatuses_id IS NULL
            GROUP BY th.tickets_id
            HAVING COUNT(th.id) = 1
        ) recs
        GROUP BY recs.name
    ) recs
    GROUP BY recs.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDIT: updated query) I'm pretty rusty on MySQL, and I don't have it installed on my machine anymore, but I think you can do something like:

```
SELECT dte, name, COUNT(name) FROM
  (SELECT ts.name, Date_Format(COALESCE(th.updatedAt, th.createdAt), '%Y-%m-%d') as dte 
  FROM threads th
  INNER JOIN tickets t ON t.id = th.tickets_id
  INNER JOIN ticketstatuses ts ON th.assign_ticketStatuses_id = ts.id) AS j
GROUP BY dte, name
```

I'm reasonably sure that will give you a list of counts grouped by date, then by `ticketStatus.name`, but am more than open to correction by someone with a bit more expertise in MySQL.  In the meantime, [here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afd16/7) of the above query